# Using SAVE TRANSACTION with a linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, distributed-transactions

Inside a transaction that have a savepoint I have to make a join with a table that is in a linked server. When I try to do it, I get the error message:

```
“Cannot use SAVE TRANSACTION within a distributed transaction”
```

The remote table data rarely changes.  It is almost fixed. Is is possible to tell SqlServer to exclude this table from the transaction? I've tried a (NOLOCK) hint, but it isn't possible to use this hint for a table in a linked server.

Does anyone knows about a workaround? I'm using the ole SqlServer 2000.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is to make a local copy of the remote table *before* you start the transaction.  I know that this may sound like a lot of overhead, but remote joins are frequently a performance problem anyway and the SOP fix for that is also to make a local copy.

Answer (score 0):

According to this **[link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295027)**, the ability to use SAVEPOINTs in a Distributed transaction was dropped in SQL 7.

> To allow application migration from Microsoft SQL Server 6.5 when
>   savepoints inside distributed transactions are in use, Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2000 Service Pack 1 introduces a trace flag that allows a
>   savepoint within a distributed transaction. The trace flag is 8599 and
>   can be turned on during the SQL Server startup or within an individual
>   session (that is, prior to enabling a distributed transaction with a
>   BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION statement) by using the DBCC TRACEON
>   command. When trace flag 8599 is set to ON, SQL Server allows you to
>   use a savepoint within a distributed transaction.

So unfortunately, you may either have to drop the bounding ACID transaction, or change the `SPROC` on the remote server so that it doesn't use `SAVEPOINTs`.

**On a side note** *(Although I have seen that you have tagged it SQL SERVER 2000)* but to make a point that *SQL SERVER 2008* has **[remote proc trans Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189322%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** for this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case if the distributed table is not too large I would copy it to a temp table.  If possible, include any filtering to get the number of rows to a minimum.  Then you can proceed normally.  Another option since the data changes rarely is copy the data to a permanant table and checking if anything has changed to prevent sending to much data over the network every time you run the transaction.  You could only pull over the recent changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to handle transaction from UI level and you have Visual Studio 2008/.net fx 3.5 or + framework then you can wrap your logic with TransactionScope Class. If you dont have any frontends and you are working only on Sql Servers kindly ignore my answer...